# python feedparser - removing <script> tag and everything inside from feed after reading

Tags: python, django, feedparser

I am reading feed with feedparser, some content inside feed contains something like

```
&lt;p&gt; some word &lt;/p&gt;

&lt;script&gt;
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,"script","//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js","ga");

      ga("create", "UA-wewewefwef-13", "www.wewefwef.com");
      ga("require", "displayfeatures");
      ga("set", "anonymizeip", true);
      ga("send", "pageview");
&lt;/script&gt;
```

it is removing everything inside `&lt;script&gt;` and only reading `&lt;p&gt;`. why is it? what am I doing wrong?

ok, I found [in the docs](http://universal-feedparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#whitelist-don-t-blacklist) that feedparser automatically sanitizes the script tags. but what If the source is known to me and I want those script tags? how can I workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it:

```
feedparser.SANITIZE_HTML = 0
```

and viola!